# Capture click and keystroke events in Javascript, override default behavior?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, jquery

I've written some JavaScript code using jQuery that listens for the user to click the mouse on different parts of my page with and without holding down the shift key.

I have a table on my page.  The idea is that the user can select rows in the table by clicking on them.  The user can select multiple rows by clicking one row, holding down shift, and clicking another row.  (This is how the user expects to select multiple rows, but holding down the shift key, right?)

Anyways, my code works in Internet Explorer, but I have a problem.  My code reads the users selection, but the browser simultaneously highlights the text between the two mouse click locations.

How can I make it so that my code can select the rows based on the user clicks and the browser doesn't select the text?

**Update** I tried the following code:
`$('tr').bind('mousedown',function() { return false; } );`

With this code in my page, when I click one row, hold down shift and click another row, the text between the two rows is highlighted.  This is what I'm trying to suppress.  Please note that the text highlights *before* I release the mouse button.

**Update #2** I tried the following code:

```
   $('tr').bind('mousedown',function(e) { 
   e.preventDefault();
   return false;
   });
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to do anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

It's the *mousedown* event you want to suppress.

Have a look at [event.stopPropogation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) and [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).

Comment: Hmmm....  I successfully used this technique with the `contextmenu` event.  I tried it with the .click event; now I'll try it with mousedown.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of an event handler is ignored by specification (jQuery might to additional stuff).

You may be looking for `preventDefault` and `returnValue` (this latter one was invented precisely because the return value of a handler is ignored).

You may also want to look into the CSS3 property extension `-moz-user-select: none`.

Comment: Returning false from a jquery event handler calls both `preventDefault` and `stopPropogation`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function(){

  $("tableSelector").bind('selectstart mousedown',function () { 
      return false; 
  });

});
```

Comment: What is the selector you used?

Comment: $('tr') is the selector I used.  To repeat, there is no trouble distinguishing which row I clicked, but I can't seem to override the text selection behavior

Comment: What do you mean by "the table selector of this tr"?

Comment: Do you have any classname or id to the table in which this tr is?

Comment: So, you meant $('tr#myTable')?

Comment: Just use $("#myTable"). You want the text selection to be disabled for all the trs in this table, right?